# switching from nvidia to intel gpu keeping nvida driver

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 15.10, cuda

I want to debug a cuda application in the nvidia card. However it shows an error

`All CUDA devices are used for display and cannot be used while debugging`

Hence I want the display to use intel graphics. But I **dont want to remove or blacklist nvidia drivers** as I require the same for running cuda.

Is there any possible solution to keep the nvidia card active and at the same time not use it for display? I am using ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 1):

Try creating `intel.conf` file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` directory. Create the directory if it doesn't exist. File content should be as follows:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "My intel card"
    Driver         "intel"
EndSection
```

Then restart your X server. I'm not sure about the config directory location in 15.10. You can check it by analysing /var/log/Xorg.0.conf. It should contain following line:

```
[   timestamp] (==) Using system config directory "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
```

OR

```
[   timestamp] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
```

In the latter case of course you should move your file to the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`

If your log contains something like `Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf` try moving the file aside (for example renaming to xorg.conf.wasgood).

After X server restart you should get X windows running on intel driver, leaving your nvidia ready for CUDA magic.

Comment: I created the intel conf file with the following contents `Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Intel Haswell Integrated Graphics Controller"
    Driver         "intel"
EndSection`. After that I moved the xorg conf file. But when I restart X (service gdm restart) it automatically recreates the xorg conf file and it still uses nvidia

Comment: So try copying the content of the file you've created as xorg.conf file. Maybe it won't be overwritten.

Comment: I tried it now. But the xorg.conf file is overwritten. The new one has an intel section (it was there previously also). but it is made inactive `Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"`. I tired switching nvidia and intel. But it does not working

Comment: See if this helps: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1310489

Comment: even after commenting the start on gpu manager it still overwrites. when I give the driver as intel, it just crashes and i915 (lshw shows the driver is i915) it overwrites the configuration

Comment: Could you try not to use login manager, but start X session using `startx` command?

Comment: I tried startX and it shows "Failed to Initialize GLX Extension (Compatible Nvidia X Driver Not Found". Even the configuration which works with `gdm start` is not working with startX